# Use custom locale in devise emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, i18n-gem

I am using `devise_invitable` gem in rails and I have configured a number of locales in my rails app. What I would like to do is to invite a user with a locale I would specify myself. I t could look something like this:

```
User.invite!(:email => "test@example.com", :locale => 'fr')
```

This would send an email with the 'fr' as locale , even when `I18n.locale` would be `en`.

Is this possible, *even with a complete different syntax than the one I am using above* ?

Answer (score 0):

Digging, I found that `devise_invitable` uses the `devise` mailer, see [source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/mailers/helpers.rb#L80-83). I'm not 100% sure how `I18n.t` exactly works, but I suppose you know that. So use [`alias_method_chain`](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/03/06/alias_method_chain-in-models/) to monkey-patch the `translate` method. To pass the other language, you can choose one:

1. modify the whole call stack to pass down the variable
2. use a pseudo-global variable via [`Thread.current[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-i-5B-5D).

I propose to use 2., make your choice. Then use that variable to return the correct translation.